# Installing a new Magento Extension requires logout/login, otherwise you get 404 in admin page

Tags: magento

I was told by two different people that the following is a known issue with Magento:

> When installing a new extension, the admin tries to access the
>   configuration of the extension, and gets a 404 page. The way to
>   resolve this issue is to logout and then login into his admin panel.

- Is there a way to work around this issue when designing an extension?
- Is there an open issue about this?

Here is [one page I found](http://opensclub.org/forums/topic/magento-extension-configuration-page-shows-404-error/) that talks about this issue.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It happens because when you login to the admin panel magento reads ACL rules and writes them to the session. When you install new module you define new ACL rules that are not listed in your session.

When you install modulefrom magento connect you have "clear session" button to force renewal.

In module you can use something like

```
$session = $adminuser = Mage::getSingleton('admin/session');
/* @var $adminuser Mage_Admin_Model_User */
$adminuser = $session->getUser();
$adminuser->setReloadAclFlag(true);

$session->refreshAcl();
```

You can also look at [this](https://github.com/ikonoshirt/reloadAcl) extension how to add "reload Acl" button to the admin panel.