# Free Facebook Connect error 404 not found

Tags: magento

I installed Magento Extension Facebook Connect 
http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/facebookfreebelvg-4448.html
But when I go to configuration -> facebook I receive an error: 404 error, page not found
can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

Clear cache etc.. This is simple stuff to know for working with 3rd party extensions in Magento.

*Ps. http://store.belvg.com/media/Facebook%20Connect%20and%20Like%20User%20Guide.pdf*

Answer (score 0):

Log out of the admin panel and log in again, so that the ACL can be reloaded.

Related question with more info: [Installing a new Magento Extension requires logout/login, otherwise you get 404 in admin page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12956794/installing-a-new-magento-extension-requires-logout-login-otherwise-you-get-404)